# Executing a.out on Android

Tags: android, c, file, execute

I compiled, assembled and linked a File on Android (ARM) and want to execute it on Android (ARM).
I have got a a.out file in my /data/data/Package.AppName/files folder.
The file exists and if I try to get information about it with file i get the output:

```
a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
```

So i am sure the file exists in this directory.
If I access this file from Java IsReadable is true, IsWriteable is true and IsExecutable is true.
I try to execute it with the command:

```
/data/data/Package.AppName/files/a.out
```

But this get me following strace:

```
9001  execve("/data/data/Package.AppName/files/a.out", ["/data/data/Package.AppName/files/a.out"], [/* 16 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)  
9001  dup(2)                            = 3  
9001  fcntl64(3, F_GETFL)               = 0x1 (flags O_WRONLY)  
9001  close(3)                          = 0  
9001  write(2, "strace: exec: No such file or directory\n", 40) = 40  
9001  exit_group(1)                     = ?
```

**EDIT 1:**
I am checking if the file exists and which permissions it has right before executing with:

```
ls -l strace -f data/data/.../files/a.out
```

This gives me -rwx------ u0_a63 u0_a63   4583 2013-05-17 17:07 a.out
So this file exists. I execute just by calling it with:

```
String[] command = {"strace", "-f", "data/data/.../files/a.out"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

**EDIT 2:**
I used:

```
f.setReadable(true, false);  
f.setWritable(true, false);
f.setExecutable(true, false)
```

and now it has permission -rwxrwxrwx, but still the same problem.
I compiled it step by step (compile, assemble, link) with the android-gcc-4.4.0 toolchain from: http://code.google.com/p/native-android-development/downloads/detail?name=android-gcc-4.4.0.tar.gz&can=2&q=

Any idea why this gives my ENOENT ?
Any help appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think you don't have the permission required to run it, so it seems.

Comment: Could be possible, but how to get the permission. I do not have a rooted phone, but also executed c files in apps like "Terminal Emulator", which does not require root permission.

Comment: Can you programatically make sure the file is there before calling it? Can you post the code that 'invokes' / runs the file? We only know that the file is there because `you told us to trust you it's there` :) see if you can execute the file in Putty or anything else, without sudo and then with sudo. Check the file permissions, check if it's 0644 or 777 (rwxrwxrwx) and update :)

Comment: Can't help wondering if there is something funny about your executable or its library dependencies.  What happens if you copy some known-to-work executable from /system/bin to your files directory and try to execute that instead?

Comment: Which "known-to-work executable from /system/bin" do you mean ?

Comment: Anyone you like.  Most of them are symlinks to toolbox, but seem to work regardless - I used /system/bin/ls for a test.

Comment: Ok. I tested system/bin/ls for example and this works. If my File would be broken i would get an other error but ENOENT, or am I wrong ?